# Click wouldn't let me pass multiple files, although it should be possible

Tags: python, python-click

I'm trying to use click for multiple files. For example:

```
@cli.command("test")
@click.argument('input', type=click.File('rb'))
def test(input):
    with click.progressbar(input, label='READING') as bar:
        for x in bar:
            pass
```

When I do something like this:

```
script test ~/ololo/*
```

I get:

```
Error: Got unexpected extra arguments ( ... listing all files in folder ...)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `nargs` parameter. If it is set to -1, then an unlimited number of arguments is accepted: http://click.pocoo.org/6/arguments/#variadic-arguments

```
@cli.command("test")
@click.argument('input', nargs=-1, type=click.File('rb'))
def test(input):
    with click.progressbar(input, label='READING') as bar:
        for x in bar:
            pass
```

Comment: Thank you, it should definitely be documented in the section about working with files. Gonna leave an issue later. Have a nice day.