# reading multiple files using arg parse module in python

Tags: python

I want to open multiple files at a time using arg parse module.here is the code that open only one file.help me to open multiple files.

```
import argparse
import csv
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('filename',type=argparse.FileType('r'), help='open a certain file',nargs='*')
args = parser.parse_args()
file_name=args.filename
next(file_name)
dic=csv.DictReader(file_name,delimiter=',')
for reading in dic:
    print(reading)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Some loops? Show some efforts.

Comment: i have more than 100 files with .txt extension.i just want to open files using key word year.for example [lahore_weather_1996_Dec.txt].i want to iterate through all files and open all files that contain keyword 1996 in it.i am blank and have no idea how to do it.

Comment: your method opens the file handles. You need the file names, and open manually if filter matches.

Comment: how can i manually open more than hundred files?can we do this by providing path of the folder that contain multiples files?and then iterate through each filename and get the files of our choice?

Comment: Not really an answer, but I find [click](http://click.pocoo.org/) to be a vastly superior library for command line parsing. Apparently, [someone has asked about multiple files with click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34762947/1394393) before.

Answer (score 2):

> **Question**:  help me to open multiple files. ... want to open files using key word year

Use a **Filepath with Wildcards** and a **Keyword** Parameter, for instance:

> **Note**: If your Foldername conflict with the Keyword you have to extract the Filename Part from Filepath and match against the Filename.

```
import argparse, glob, csv
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('filepath', help='Path to File, could have Wildcards', nargs=1)
parser.add_argument('keyword', help='Keyword in Filepath', nargs=1)
args = parser.parse_args()

# Use glob to expand the Wildcards
# Loop the List of File Path
for fpath in glob.glob(args.filepath[0]):

    # Condition True if Keyword in Filepath
    if fpath.find(args.keyword[0]) >= 0:
        print('MATCH({})'.format(fpath))

        # Open this File an process it
        with open(fpath) as fh:
            dic = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=',')
            for reading in dic:
                print(reading)
```

> **Usage**:
>
> ```
> python DictReader.py *.txt 1996
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Most shells will expand wildcards so that the python interpreter will see the actual file names instead of the string '*.txt'.